# Mustache, Twitter Bootstrap, NodeJS Plain HTML returned

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, mustache

When I'm trying to use the example from here:
https://github.com/raycmorgan/Mu

```
var http = require('http')
  , util = require('util')
  , mu   = require('mu2');

mu.root = __dirname + '/templates';

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

  var stream = mu.compileAndRender('index.html', {name: "john"});
  util.pump(stream, res);

}).listen(8000);
```

I get a plain HTML file back (no twitter bootstrap fanciness).

Are there additional options required to allow it to serve the CSS and whatnot along with the .html file?

I would love to use the simplicity I found with the connect package to serve files ( if I don't want to use mustache I can serve the twitter bootstrapified html file no problem, it's when I try to route it through the below that it doesn't work, but if I want mustache I'm not sure what the best way is, most tutorials out there use the express.createServer, but I am seeing a message that it's no longer supposed to be used that way).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to serve static content (such as js/css) you have to tell node where to serve it from and where it is. However, for simplicity I would recommend that you use Express.

I apologize if you already know the following, but I'll say it just incase.

To get you started you can `npm install -g express` which will install Express globally with the command line tool, then run the `express` command (in an empty directory) to create a (super)basic Express application. Inside the app.js file created you will see that it's using Connect static middleware to serve static css/js/img files, and has created a few basic routes to get you started.

You'll also notice that it creates the express server using `var app = express();` (at least I believe it does).